# allocating memory when overriding + operator in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am creating a custom object and overriding the + operator.  I am return a new object of the same type.  Is it bad practise to allocate memory inside this method? because I then I will need to delete the memory out of scope.

Comment: Why do you need to allocate anything in the first place? Operator+ means your object has value-semantics, so there shouldn't be any sort of dynamic allocation. If there is, it's probably best to choose a different function name.

Comment: @KerrekSB - `string::operator+` allocates memory.

Comment: @Rob: Good point -- exception that proves the rule? String also knows how to clean up after itself. :-) [Actually, are you sure that the plus-operator allocates? I'd imagine that there'd be some combination of constructor and `append()` or `insert()` that handles the actual allocation.]

Comment: The difference is that `string::operator+` allocates memory (or, calls code that allocates memory, which is the same thing) that is "owned" and managed in an object of type `string` returned by value. That's fine. A common pattern of `operator+` is copy-and-+=, and if the class manages memory (which `string` does) then at least the copy will allocate. Although the questioner doesn't specifically say so, it looks as if he is planning to dynamically allocate a new instance to return, which is just wrong. If you want to do that, don't call the function `operator+`, call it something else.

Comment: @Kerreck: actually you might not want to implement `string::operator+` by a copy followed by an `append/insert` simply for efficiency -- you want if possible to first create a string with a big enough buffer for the two operands combined, then copy them both in. Avoids doing an initial allocation that's not big enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, without further information, it is bad.

Usually you do:

```
struct X
{
     int m_i;
     X(int i) : m_i(i) {  }

     X operator+(const X& another) const
     {
         return X(m_i + another.m_i); // note, not new X(...)
     }
}
```

That said, you could return a unique_ptr if you really had to allocate dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice example of overloading `operator+` to return a **new** instance of the object as the result, **without** dynamic allocation.

The source is [here](http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html), with a lot of explanations on how to overload operators.

The example is this:

```
  // Add this instance's value to other, and return a new instance
  // with the result.
  const MyClass MyClass::operator+(const MyClass &other) const {
    return MyClass(*this) += other;
  }
```

It assumes you implemented `operator+=` and a copy constructor, if you don't have `+=` - just put the assignment operations there directly. Read the link for more details.

Comment: Note that returning `const MyClass` has the benefit of stopping someone from writing `(a + b) = c`, but the disadvantage that it impedes C++11 move semantics, and in C++03 it impedes the equivalent "swaptimization", `(b+c).swap(a)`. Basically, if I want to write `a = b + c` (as an assignment, not an initialization), then for efficiency I need `b + c` to return something mutable. Of course if `MyClass` is trivial to copy then it makes no difference.